# SQLite copy column values to a new column and/or with function

Tags: android, sqlite, copy, tablecolumn

This is SQLite for Android...

I am inserting a new column using ALTER TABLE tablename ADD COLUMN.

I have 2 questions:

1. Is there a way I can just copy values from existing columnA to this newly inserted/added columnB?
2. I need to add another columnC, the value of which is MD5 hash output of columnA. Is there a way SQLite can add columnC and set its value to MD5 hash (either using an existing SQLite internal function or my custom function)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. `UPDATE MyTable SET NewCol = columnA`
2. The Android DB API does not expose a mechanism for registering custom functions.
   You have to read all the `columnA` values, compute the hash in your code, and update the records one by one.